# Dialog API: Dialog can't send messages after redirection in Excel Online

Tags: office-js

I leverage the dialog API and ADAL.js for authentication. The dialog code determines if the user is authenticated, and (using ADAL.js) navigates to the AAD login page with appropriate properties if the user isn't yet authenticated. When the AAD page completes, it redirects back to the dialog, at which point it recognizes it's complete and sends a message back to the add-in.

The add-in then closes the dialog and progresses with its flow, now having the ability to acquire tokens.

The dialog has worked for us without issue until recently when it lit up in Excel Online. We initially had to make some changes to adjust the load order, so that the ADAL.js code could handle window callbacks before trying to initialize Office, since (when running in Excel online) Office couldn't be initialized in the frames ADAL.js uses for acquiring tokens. We refactored the code, and now avoid initializing Office when framed.

However, we recently discovered another strange issue that only affects IE and Edge (Chrome and Firefox work fine). For some reason when the dialog is navigated back to after the AAD page, it is unable to send messages back to the parent. Oddly enough, if the page is reloaded, the message can be sent fine; just not immediately after the AAD redirection.

We worked around this issue by reloading the dialog after sending the message, but this seems like an odd issue that should be investigated. Below is a snippet of our dialog code.

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext({
    instance: localStorage.adalConfigInstance,
    clientId: localStorage.adalConfigClientID,
    tenant: (localStorage.adalConfigTenant ? localStorage.adalConfigTenant : "common"),
    cacheLocation: "localStorage",
    redirectUri: window.location.href.replace(window.location.hash, ""),
    displayCall: function (location) {
        if (localStorage.oauthTwoFactorForcedClientID) {
            location = location.replace("response_type=id_token", "response_type=id_token+token") + "&resource=" + localStorage.oauthTwoFactorForcedClientID;
        }
        window.location.replace(location);
    }
});

var initialLoad = localStorage.oauthInitialLogin === "true";
localStorage.oauthInitialLogin = "false";

authContext.handleWindowCallback();

// Only initialize Office if the dialog isn't framed (e.g. not an ADAL token acquisition frame)
if (window.parent === window) {
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function authenticationDialogLoaded() {
            function login() {
                if (initialLoad) {
                    authContext.login();
                } else {
                    // This modifies the dialog to show login content
                }
            }

            function fail(error) {
                Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify({ error: error }));
            }

            function authenticated() {
                Office.context.ui.messageParent("authenticated");
            }

            if (sessionStorage.authenticated) {
                authenticated();
            } else {
                var loginError = authContext.getLoginError();
                if (!initialLoad && loginError) {
                    fail(loginError);
                    return;
                }
                var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
                if (user) {
                    window.setTimeout(function acquireToken() {
                        authContext.acquireToken(localStorage.adalResourceID, function tokenAcquired(error, token) {
                            if (error) {
                                if (initialLoad) {
                                    login();
                                } else {
                                    fail(error);
                                }
                            } else if (!token) {
                                login();
                            } else {
                                authenticated();
                                sessionStorage.authenticated = true;
                                window.setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(true); }, 0);
                            }
                        });
                    }, 0);
                } else {
                    login();
                }
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Has anyone seen this before / is anyone aware of this already?

--- Update 2/21 ---

We've had customers from another supported product indicate they weren't able to authenticate online. I retried our "refresh" solution today, and it no longer works. It doesn't seem we're able to leverage the dialog API online in the current state, so I'm adding a workaround to our authentication code so that we pop a window when running online regardless of dialog API support.

Comment: Is the first page of the dialog on exactly the same domain as the opener?  If not you might experience an issue like the one you describe, IE/Edge will prevent messaging back, its a known issue with those browsers.

Comment: @Humberto Lezama Yes, in fact we use a regular expression to replace the page based on the location's href:
        window.location.href.replace(authentication.AppPageRegex, "/App/AuthenticationDialog.html")